# Python: using CalculateField_management for duplicating attributes with a double quotation mark

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I am writing a python script which duplicates a field. The field contains names of pipelines but some of these names has double quotation (ex. 8" NGL PIPELINE). I have created a new field and trying to copy the attributes using:

arcpy.CalculateField_management(PL_XING_SUMMARY,"PLNAME", "'!FIRST_PLNA!'", "PYTHON_9.3");

But the script double quotes whole attributes (ex. "8" NGL PIPELINE"). Is there a way to remove the double quotation marks at the start and end of each attribute?

P.S. I am using ArcGIS version 10.1 Service Pack 5

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't getting rid of the extra quotes work? That is:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(PL_XING_SUMMARY,"PLNAME", '!FIRST_PLNA!', "PYTHON_9.3");
```

Comment: @user20688 I just ran same test using your string at ArcGIS 10.2 and it worked fine for me too.  As an aside there is no SP5 for 10.1 so I am thinking you must be using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 SP5 and have adjusted your tags accordingly.